# How do I Install Intermediate Certificates (in AWS)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, load-balancing

I have installed private key (pem encoded) and public key certificate (pem encoded) on Amazon Load Balancer.  However, when I check the SSL with [site test tool](http://www.networking4all.com/en/support/tools/site+check/), I get the following error:

> Error while checking the SSL Certificate!! Unable to get the local
>   issuer of the certificate. The issuer of a locally looked up
>   certificate could not be found. Normally this indicates that not all
>   intermediate certificates are installed on the server.

I converted crt file to pem using these commands from this [tutorial](http://moze.koze.net/?p=81):

```
openssl x509 -in input.crt -out input.der -outform DER
openssl x509 -in input.der -inform DER -out output.pem -outform PEM
```

During setup of Amazon Load Balancer, the only option I left out was certificate chain. (pem encoded) However, this was optional. Could this be cause of my issue? And if so; How do I create certificate chain?

**UPDATE**

If you make request to VeriSign they will give you a certificate chain. This chain includes public crt, intermediate crt and root crt. Make sure to remove the public crt from your certificate chain (which is the top most certificate) before adding it to your certification chain box of your Amazon Load Balancer.

If you are making HTTPS requests from an Android app, then above instruction may not work for older Android OS such as 2.1 and 2.2. To make it work on older Android OS:

- [go here](https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=AR657&actp=LIST&viewlocale=en_US)
- click on "retail ssl" tab and then click on "secure site" > "CA Bundle for Apache Server"
- copy and past these intermediate certs into certificate chain box. just incase if you have not found it [here is the direct link](https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=AR1409).

If you are using geo trust certificates then the solution is much the same for Android devices, however, you need to copy and paste their intermediate certs for Android.

Comment: Intermediate Certificate == Chain Certificate

Comment: thanks @chris, can you tell me how i can create chain certificate. i have tried googling however i'm really confused how to create this chain certificate. any suggestions or links to tutorial is much appreciated

Comment: @getmizanur Where's this certificate from?  The CA provider should be able to provide you with the PEM-encoded chain.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

concatenate the files provided manually, in the following order:

- site.com.crt
- intermediate.crt  (one or more, the order of these doesn't matter)
- ROOT.crt

you can do this from a shell with the `cat` command

`cat site.com intermediate.crt ROOT.crt > site.chain.pem`

or copy/paste them, no whitespace between, make sure certificates are on different lines

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
site cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
intermediate cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
root cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: thanks @eric, i only have two files signed .crt and .key. can you tell   me how i can get intermediate and root crt files?

Comment: https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&id=AR1735

Comment: concatenate the site cert with those intermediates, without root cert.

Comment: @EricFortis If the AWS load balancer wants a separate certificate file and chain file, it might just want the intermediate(s) and root, without the subject cert - not sure!

Answer (score 7):

I had issues w/ my rapid-ssl cert; as per

https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO21856&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1368427636740

I could fix it by reversing the certificates in in the CA bundle:

> Problem
>
> When installing an SSL certificate into Amazon Web Service (AWS) - Amazon EC2 device, you may 
>   receive the following error message.
>
> Error: Invalid Public Key Certificate.
>   Cause
>   This problem may occur on Amazon Web Service (AWS) - Amazon EC2 device when any of the following 
>   conditions are true.
>
> ```
> RapidSSL Intermediate CA bundle certificate is not installed on Amazon Web Service (AWS) - > Amazon EC2 device
> RapidSSL Intermediate CA bundle certificate is installed on Amazon Web Service (AWS) - Amazon > EC2 device but the CA bundle required needs to be installed in reversed order
> ```
>
> Resolution
>
> To resolve the error from installing RapidSSL certificate using Amazon Web Service (AWS) - Amazon EC2 device, perform the following steps.
>
> Step 1: Download Intermediate CA Bundle Certificate
>
> To download the Intermediate CA bundle certificate, refer to article AR1548
>
> When viewing the CA bundle you will see two certificates stacked on top of each other. These two 
>   certificates will need to be switched. The top certificate needs to be placed on the bottom and the 
>   bottom certificate needs to be placed on top.
>
> ...

Comment: reversing certificates in my ca-bunle file worked like a charm. thanks!

Comment: This. This is the correct answer. You helped me so much.

Answer (score 5):

I had to go through the same issue. Just by uploading a pem file with the following seem to resolve the problem. It did not like site cert at the top

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
intermediate cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
root cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Your answer is not very clear but looks very similar to the already given and accepted one.  Is it really another answer to the question?

Comment: this answer worked for me. I followed the accepted answer by including the site cert but that didnt work. Just by putting the intermediate cert and root cert as mentioned in this answer worked great!

Answer (score 4):

For Comodo issued certs

```
    Private Key: private_key.text
    Public Key Certificate: yourdomain.crt
    Certificate Chain: combine these 2
    cat COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt > certchain.txt
    (or paste in COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt first followd by COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I, too, have purhcased a RapidSSL certificate and have been struggling with the "Invalid Public Key Certificate" error. I tried everything listed here, including reversing the chain certificates, ommitting them, appending them to the main server certificate, etc...

In the end, I just couldn't get the error to go away. So I found another way to upload a certificate to Amazon for use with the Load Balancer (Elastic Beanstalk): There is actually a GUI that allows uploading certificates!

It's located in EC2 -> Load Balancers -> Select your load balancer -> Listnerers (tab) -> Select HTTPS in the dropdown menu -> Click Select under the SSL certificate tab and a form pops up that allows you to upload your certificate!

[image: GUI]

Once I pasted the files in there, it worked like a charm!

Comment: Also, make sure you are trying to upload an "RSA Private Key". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733536/how-do-i-convert-a-private-key-to-an-rsa-private-key