# SSL problems on Android (Intermediate Certificate)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, ssl-certificate, android, amazon-beanstalk

My site works well on every browser and device, except on Android, where it throws a security exception. I already installed my SSL certificate on my Amazon Elastic Beanstalk instance (by installing the certificate on the load balancer).

It seems that I can be falling on the following case:

http://blog.michaelfmcnamara.com/2011/07/googleandroid-root-and-intermediate-certificate-issues/

It seems that I have to install a intermediate certificate.

Can anyone help me with that? I dont really know what it means

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate the files provided manually, in the following order:

- site.com.crt
- intermediate.crt (one or more, the order of these doesn't matter)
- ROOT.crt

you can do this from a shell with the `cat` command

`cat site.com intermediate.crt ROOT.crt > site.chain.pem`

or copy/paste them, no whitespace between, make sure certificates are on different lines

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
site cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
intermediate cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
root cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

If you don't have the root, concatenate the site cert with the intermediates, without root the cert. Such as:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
site cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
intermediate cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

[How do I Install Intermediate Certificates (in AWS)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/393822/how-do-i-install-intermediate-certificates-in-aws)

Comment: site.com is the certificate that I am already using ? 
Where is the Root cert? Do I have to download from the CA?

Comment: If you don't have the root, just concatenate the intermediate cert to the site cert and then upload.

Comment: I got this message from Amazon 400 MalformedCertificate Invalid Public Key Certificate.

Comment: Does your file look like the update I added above for site cert + intermediate cert?

Comment: yes.... -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
A LOT OF STUFF
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ALOT OF STUFF
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: comments doesnt preserve line breaks, but yes... it looks like your answer

Comment: I am using the following command to upload: iam-servercertupload -b full_cert.crt -k private-key.pem -s  20131105_testcert  -v --aws-credential-file aws_cred

Comment: Do I have to change anything on my private key?

Comment: Are your certs in PEM format? http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/08/15/setting-up-ssl-on-an-amazon-elastic-load-balancer/

Comment: I am not sure, but I used to use the same command to upload the certificate and it worked fine (without appending the intermediate). Does it make sense?

Comment: I donwloaded a certificate from my certificate authority. I dont know if it's a pem format

Comment: Ok, it seems that my intermediate certificate is wrong, without that it works well. I tried to convert it to .pem and it didnt worked either. Any ideas?

Comment: GO to your certificate provider and ask for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to upload the intermediate certificate as well to prove it has been signed by a root authority.  You must do something like the following using the AWS command line tools:

```
iam-servercertupload -b mydomain.crt -k mydomain.nopass.key -c my_intermediate_cert.crt -s mydomain
```

Alternatively, it can be done through the GUI control panel.  Whoever you purchased the cert from should be able to provide the appropriate intermediate cert(s).