# facebook app giving Security error when click on a shared link to my site

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildcard

I have built a site and users are sharing it on facebook, but when one of their friends click on the link it give them this error.

> Security error
>
> There are problems with the security certificate for this site.

It only gives them this error when in the facebook app. My hosting is through aws, I have a wildcard cert on the site.

This is the only thread that talks about this, but does not give an actual course of action.

https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10153289930849400

Does anyone know how to fix this? Am I supposed to go to aws and resolve this or to facebook? It is really confusing considering I get no warning from anyone else that the certs are having problems.

******UPDATE******

This error only appears to be showing in the facebook app on android.

Comment: What is the URL? How did you configure SSL?

Comment: https://gladitood.com/ I got my cert from RapidSSL, it does not expire until 2017. I followed these instruction http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/ssl-server-cert.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick visit to ssllabs.com shows that [your server is failing to send an intermediate certificate](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=gladitood.com&s=107.23.139.65) "RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3". [Add this intermediate certificate to your Elastic Load Balancer.](https://serverfault.com/q/393822/126632)